# Springfox Swagger2 - @ApiOperation not working

Tags: java, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I use springfox-swagger2 for my Spring MVC REST API. Everything works good with swagger but my problem is I cannot add additional information to my swagger documentation.

Maven Dependency:

```
<!-- Swagger -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

My Swagger config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan("path.to.controller.package")
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket customImplementation() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SPRING_WEB).apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    @Bean
    public UiConfiguration uiConfig() {

        return UiConfiguration.DEFAULT;
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo("Service API", "Simple REST Service", "0.0.1",
                "mail@mail.com", "mail@mail.com", " ", " ");
        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

My controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/persons")
public class PersonController {

    Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ApiOperation(value = "doStuff", response = Person.class)
    @ApiImplicitParams({@ApiImplicitParam(name="Authorization", value="MY DESCRIPTION")})
    public @ResponseBody Person getPerson(@PathVariable String id,
          @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authToken) throws Exception {

          //do things and return
    }
}
```

So, calling the swagger-ui the controller is shown, the method, everything except my additional infos defined in `@ApiOperation` and `@ApiImplicitParams`. Does anyone have an idea from where the problem can come from? The params are also not in the JSON file which is created from swagger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace your `customImplementation()` method by:

```
@Bean
public Docket customImplementation() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .build()
        .apiInfo(apiInfo());
}
```

Build the project, and then your additional infos should appear.

**EDIT**: I don't know if it makes any difference, but I am using these dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: perfect - thank you, the change in the customImplementation() made it working